# Lendo JSON com muitos arrays com PHP

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando tratar esse JSON com PHP mas não consigo retornar os dados para alguma variável. Quando tento acessar uma posição do mesmo é retornado `null`.

```
$url = 'https://api.hgbrasil.com/finance?format=json';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

print_r($obj);
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
echo $obj->[currencies]->[USD]->[buy];
```

Esse é o JSON retornado:

```
{"by":"default","valid_key":true,"results":{"currencies":{"source":"BRL","USD":{"name":"Dollar","buy":3.8732,"sell":null,"variation":-1.078},"EUR":{"name":"Euro","buy":4.3412,"sell":null,"variation":-1.46},"GBP":{"name":"Pound Sterling","buy":5.0878,"sell":null,"variation":-0.611},"ARS":{"name":"Argentine Peso","buy":0.0905,"sell":null,"variation":-0.11},"BTC":{"name":"Bitcoin","buy":17082.794,"sell":17082.794,"variation":1.445}},"stocks":{"IBOVESPA":{"name":"BM\u0026F BOVESPA","location":"Sao Paulo, Brazil","points":96538.117,"variation":1.18},"NASDAQ":{"name":"NASDAQ Stock Market","location":"New York City, United States","points":7796.71,"variation":0.87},"CAC":{"name":"CAC 40","location":"Paris, French","variation":1.03},"NIKKEI":{"name":"Nikkei 225","location":"Tokyo, Japan","variation":1.43}},"available_sources":["BRL"],"bitcoin":{"blockchain_info":{"name":"Blockchain.info","format":["USD","en_US"],"last":4160.86,"buy":4160.86,"sell":4160.86,"variation":1.445},"coinbase":{"name":"Coinbase","format":["USD","en_US"],"last":4142.7,"variation":1.537},"bitstamp":{"name":"BitStamp","format":["USD","en_US"],"last":4142.95,"buy":4142.83,"sell":4141.33,"variation":1.698},"foxbit":{"name":"FoxBit","format":["BRL","pt_BR"],"last":16745.68,"variation":2.72},"mercadobitcoin":{"name":"Mercado Bitcoin","format":["BRL","pt_BR"],"last":16489.95994,"buy":16400.0,"sell":16489.95994,"variation":1.227},"omnitrade":{"name":"OmniTrade","format":["BRL","pt_BR"],"last":16250.0,"buy":16250.0,"sell":16610.0,"variation":0.994},"xdex":{"name":"XDEX","format":["BRL","pt_BR"],"last":16299.0,"variation":1.154}},"taxes":[{"date":"2019-03-29","cdi":6.4,"selic":6.4,"daily_factor":1.0002462}]},"execution_time":0.0,"from_cache":true}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para manipular um JSON, você precisa primeiro saber [a sua sintaxe](https://www.json.org/). Quando o JSON é delimitado por chaves (`{` e `}`), ele corresponde a um *JSON object*, que é um conjunto de vários pares "chave/valor".

Por exemplo:

```
{
  "nome": "Fulano",
  "idade": 25
}
```

Este é um *JSON object* que possui a chave `nome`, cujo valor é a string `"Fulano"`, e a chave `idade`, cujo valor é o número `25`.

O detalhe é que os valores podem ser outros *objects*. Ex:

```
{
  "nome": "Fulano",
  "idade": 25,
  "contatos": {
    "telefone": "(11) 91234-5678",
    "email": "fulano@email.com"
  }
}
```

Neste caso, o valor correspondente à chave `contatos` é outro *object*, que por sua vez possui duas chaves: `telefone` e `email`, cujos valores são, respectivamente, as strings `"(11) 91234-5678"` e `"fulano@email.com"`.

---

Sendo assim, o JSON que você está manipulando é um *object*, que possui *objects* dentro de outros *objects* e assim por diante.

No PHP, quando você usa a função [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) com o segundo parâmetro igual a `true`, o retorno é um array associativo. Então vamos imprimir o array correspondente ao seu JSON:

```
$str = '{"by":"default","valid_key":true,"results":{"currencies":{"source":"BRL","USD":{"name":"Dollar","buy":3.8732,"sell":null,"variation":-1.078},"EUR":{"name":"Euro","buy":4.3412,"sell":null,"variation":-1.46},"GBP":{"name":"Pound Sterling","buy":5.0878,"sell":null,"variation":-0.611},"ARS":{"name":"Argentine Peso","buy":0.0905,"sell":null,"variation":-0.11},"BTC":{"name":"Bitcoin","buy":17082.794,"sell":17082.794,"variation":1.445}},"stocks":{"IBOVESPA":{"name":"BM\u0026F BOVESPA","location":"Sao Paulo, Brazil","points":96538.117,"variation":1.18},"NASDAQ":{"name":"NASDAQ Stock Market","location":"New York City, United States","points":7796.71,"variation":0.87},"CAC":{"name":"CAC 40","location":"Paris, French","variation":1.03},"NIKKEI":{"name":"Nikkei 225","location":"Tokyo, Japan","variation":1.43}},"available_sources":["BRL"],"bitcoin":{"blockchain_info":{"name":"Blockchain.info","format":["USD","en_US"],"last":4160.86,"buy":4160.86,"sell":4160.86,"variation":1.445},"coinbase":{"name":"Coinbase","format":["USD","en_US"],"last":4142.7,"variation":1.537},"bitstamp":{"name":"BitStamp","format":["USD","en_US"],"last":4142.95,"buy":4142.83,"sell":4141.33,"variation":1.698},"foxbit":{"name":"FoxBit","format":["BRL","pt_BR"],"last":16745.68,"variation":2.72},"mercadobitcoin":{"name":"Mercado Bitcoin","format":["BRL","pt_BR"],"last":16489.95994,"buy":16400.0,"sell":16489.95994,"variation":1.227},"omnitrade":{"name":"OmniTrade","format":["BRL","pt_BR"],"last":16250.0,"buy":16250.0,"sell":16610.0,"variation":0.994},"xdex":{"name":"XDEX","format":["BRL","pt_BR"],"last":16299.0,"variation":1.154}},"taxes":[{"date":"2019-03-29","cdi":6.4,"selic":6.4,"daily_factor":1.0002462}]},"execution_time":0.0,"from_cache":true}';
$obj = json_decode($str, true);
var_dump($obj);
```

A saída é (omiti várias linhas por questões de brevidade):

```
array(5) {
  ["by"]=>
  string(7) "default"
  ["valid_key"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["results"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["currencies"]=>
    array(6) {
      ["source"]=>
      string(3) "BRL"
      ["USD"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(6) "Dollar"
        ["buy"]=>
        float(3.8732)
        ["sell"]=>
        NULL
        ["variation"]=>
        float(-1.078)
      }
.....
```

Repare que a informação que você quer está no chave `buy` de um array, que por sua vez está na chave `USD` de outro array, que por sua vez está na chave `currencies` de outro array, que por sua vez está na chave `results` do array.

Podemos ver isso mais claramente se formatarmos o seu JSON (também com várias linhas omitidas e alguns comentários acrescentados por mim):

```
{
    "by": "default",
    "valid_key": true,
    "results": {                   <-- chave "results", valor é outro object
        "currencies": {            <-- chave "currencies", valor é outro object
            "source": "BRL",
            "USD": {               <-- chave "USD", valor é outro object
                "name": "Dollar",
                "buy": 3.8732,     <-- chave "buy", valor que você quer
                "sell": null,
                "variation": -1.078
            },
.....
```

Então para obter este valor, basta percorrer o array usando as chaves corretas. Se eu fizer `$obj['results']`, obterei o *object* correspondente à chave `results` (que é o objeto que possui a chave `currencies`).

Depois, com `$obj['results']['currencies']` eu obtenho o *object* correspondente à chave `currencies`, cujo valor é o *object* que possui a chave `USD`, e assim por diante, até chegar ao código final:

```
print($obj['results']['currencies']['USD']['buy']); // 3.8732
```

Answer (score 1):

Para acessar a posição não deveria ser usado

```
$obj['results']['currencies']['USD']['buy'];
```

?